# Streaming to Partitioned Tables BigQuery outside of listed date bounds

Tags: google-bigquery

I have noticed in the BigQuery [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#streaming_data_into_partitions) that it says that you can

> stream to partitions within the last 30 days in the past and 5
>   days in the future relative to the current date, based on current UTC
>   time.

However, I found it actually allows you to stream further back - we successfully got it to stream to a partition 6 months in the past.

Trying to stream to a date over a year ago however gives this error message:

> BigQuery error in insert operation: The destination table's partition
>   tmp$20160101 is outside the allowed bounds. You can only stream to
>   partitions within 366 days in the past and 31 days in the future
>   relative to the current date.

The error message clearly specifies the bounds as 366<->31. Is this simply a mistake the BigQuery documentation?

[Google cloud link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#streaming_data_into_partitions)

Answer (score 1):

**Latest update**: This is now strictly enforced

Answer (score 0):

This is not a mistake but a transform period to reduce the user's impact. The allowed the date range will be shorten with time goes, however what document says will be respected for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Few points:

- You are choosing `ingestion-time partitioned` method, try using      column-partitions instead             (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions)
- Also make sure you are passing a valid date to bigQuery. I just faced    this issue while date was in invalid format.